# webrtc using front camera by default in chrome 54

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, camera, webrtc

Guys i have been trying to get access to both front and rear camera for chrome using webrtc and its perfectly working, i'm able to switch between both front and rear cameras. However, by default chrome picks up the front camera, is there any way i can make chrome pick up the rear camera when the browser opens up?

```
var videoSelect = document.querySelector('select#videoSource');
var selectors = [videoSelect];

function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {
  // Handles being called several times to update labels. Preserve values.
  var values = selectors.map(function(select) {
    return select.value;
  });
  selectors.forEach(function(select) {
    while (select.firstChild) {
      select.removeChild(select.firstChild);
    }
  });
  for (var i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
    var deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
   if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput') {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label || 'camera ' + (videoSelect.length + 1);
      videoSelect.appendChild(option);
    } else {
      console.log('Some other kind of source/device: ', deviceInfo);
    }
  }
  selectors.forEach(function(select, selectorIndex) {
    if (Array.prototype.slice.call(select.childNodes).some(function(n) {
      return n.value === values[selectorIndex];
    })) {
      select.value = values[selectorIndex];
    }
  });
}

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(gotDevices).catch(handleError);
```

I tried accessing the array in descending order to get the back camera first, but did not help

```
for (var  i = deviceInfos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
           ....... //code follows
```

Update: I also tried adding these lines into the above code but again the same response, opens up the front cam by default

```
for (var i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
    var deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];


   if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput' && deviceInfo.facing == "environment") {
    videoSourceId = deviceInfo.id;


    } else {
      console.log('Some other kind of source/device: ', deviceInfo);
    }
  }
//other code

var constraints = {
    video: { optional: [{sourceId: videoSourceId}] }
  };
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
      then(gotStream).then(gotDevices).catch(handleError);
}
```

PS: I tried using facingMode: "environment" in the other code, but is there any scope for that here ?

Comment: I don't understand, if you're able to switch between front and back camera, then it sounds like you are able to chose front camera and you are able to chose back camera, so why aren't you able to chose back camera after a browser restart? Please clarify your question. The order you read an array in seems irrelevant. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/40779564/918910

Comment: @jib, i meant when the page loads i want the mobile to use its rare camera. Currently when the page loads the front cam opens up, upon that as a user i have to click on a button to choose the rare camera, which is not needed in my scenario. Rare cam is my first preference.

Comment: You're using user terms. SO is for programming questions. If there's a problem with your code to open the camera when the page loads, you need to show us the code for us to comment.

Comment: @jib, I understand what you are saying. My question is simply this, how to make the chrome pick up the back camera by default ? 
i've already shared the code above which is accessing the front camera.

Comment: The code you shared only returns a list of available devices. You need to call `getUserMedia` somewhere. Without seeing that code, it's not clear to me from your question what's wrong.

Comment: OKay, here is the fiddle of webcamgrabbing code which i have used. 
https://jsfiddle.net/bofwe7z1/

Answer (score 1):

How about using ***constraints*** ?

For the BACK camera:

```
{audio:false,video:{facingMode:{exact:"environment"}}}
```

For the FRONT camera:

```
{audio:false,video:{facingMode:"user"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the facing in deviceInfo label and set the default value.

```
if(deviceInfo.label.indexOf('back') > 0) { option.selected = true; }
```