# Select rear camera on Android device - jsartoolkit5

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas, jsartoolkit

I am building a project similar to [this example](https://artoolkit.github.io/jsartoolkit5/examples/pattern_threejs.html) with `jsartoolkit5`, and I would like to be able to select the back camera of my device instead of letting `Chrome` on `Android` select the front one as default.

According to the example in this [demo](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/), I have added the code below to switch camera automatically if the device has a back camera.

```
var videoElement = document.querySelector('canvas');
function successCallback(stream) {
  window.stream = stream; // make stream available to console
  videoElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  videoElement.play();
}

function errorCallback(error) {
  console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
}

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(
  function(devices) {
    for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
      if (devices[i].kind == 'videoinput' && devices[i].label.indexOf('back') !== -1) {
        if (window.stream) {
          videoElement.src = null;
          window.stream.stop();
        }
        var constraints = {
          video: {
            optional: [{
              sourceId: devices[i].deviceId
            }]
          }
        };
        navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
      }
    }
  }
);
```

The issue is that it works perfectly for a `<video>` tag, but unluckily `jsartoolkit` renders the content inside a `canvas` and it consequently throws an error. 
I have also tried to follow the instructions in [this](https://github.com/artoolkit/jsartoolkit5/issues/37) closed issue in the Github repository, but this time I get the following error: `DOMException: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture`.

Do you know or have any suggestion on how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: 100% Working solution. See on
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53371645/9222769 https://stackoverflow.com/a/53371634/9222769

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Main problem :

You are mixing old and new getUserMedia syntax.
`navigator.getUserMedia` is deprecated, and `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` should be preferred.
Also, I think that `optional` is not part of the constraints dictionary anymore.

#### Default Solution

*This part is almost a duplicate of this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32364912/3702797*

You should be able to call directly

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: {
    facingMode: {
      exact: 'environment'
      }
    }
  })
```

**But chrome still has [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=290161)**, and even if @jib's answer states that it should work with [adpater.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) polyfill, I myself were unable to make it work on my chrome for Android.

So previous syntax will currently work only on Firefox for Android.

For chrome, you'll indeed need to use `enumerateDevices`, along with *adapter.js* to make it work, but don't mix up the syntax, and everything should be fine :

```js
let handleStream = s => {
  document.body.append(
    Object.assign(document.createElement('video'), {
      autoplay: true,
      srcObject: s
    })
  );
}

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(devices => {
  let sourceId = null;
  // enumerate all devices
  for (var device of devices) {
    // if there is still no video input, or if this is the rear camera
    if (device.kind == 'videoinput' &&
        (!sourceId || device.label.indexOf('back') !== -1)) {
      sourceId = device.deviceId;
    }
  }
  // we didn't find any video input
  if (!sourceId) {
    throw 'no video input';
  }
  let constraints = {
    video: {
      sourceId: sourceId
    }
  };
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(handleStream);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

**[Fiddle for chrome](https://jsfiddle.net/bazag50j/)** which need https.

#### Make it work with jsartoolkit

You'll have to fork jsartoolkit project and edit [*artoolkit.api.js*](https://github.com/artoolkit/jsartoolkit5/blob/f7a0e8b4c2d6a52e783a1c847e53c733ce99ada8/js/artoolkit.api.js#L1118).

The main project currently disables `mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`, so you'll need to enable it again, and you'll also have to add a check for an `sourceId` option, that we'll add later in the `ARController.getUserMediaThreeScene()` call.

You can find a rough and ugly implementation of these edits in [this fork](https://github.com/Kaiido/jsartoolkit5/blob/master/js/artoolkit.api.js).

So once it is done, you'll have to rebuild the js files, and then remember to include adapter.js polyfill in your code.

[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w18f8h20/) that uses one of the project's demo.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Kaiido, the fiddle works on Android! I have still some issue with my code, which you can find in this fiddle: jsfiddle.net/yw7ksv92 (but it is not correctly working). I have tried to insert your fiddle both in my code and in the native library, but I am still seeing the front camera when running it. Do you know what the issue may be?

Comment: @d_z90, after fast-reading jsARtoolkit sources, **yes**, you need to fork the lib... Specifically around [this line](https://github.com/artoolkit/jsartoolkit5/blob/f7a0e8b4c2d6a52e783a1c847e53c733ce99ada8/js/artoolkit.api.js#L1118), you would need to add something along  `if(configuration.sourceId){ constraints.sourceId = configuration.sourceId; }`. But it seems they did block the `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` call with an `if(false)` to only use the old syntax, which seems weird... I suspect they didn't have updated their code for Promises yet.. I may have a deeper look next few days.

Comment: @d_z90, I did an ugly fork of the project. You can probably work from there.