# How can I open rear camera in mobile device using webcam.js?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webcam.js

I am using webcam.js by https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs
and In mobile devices,  the front camera is opening by default. I want to change the default to the rear camera. 
Is there any way to change the camera device?

Comment: it doesn't seem that the package has any support for selecting the rear camera.

Comment: related but not exactly but here's a reference: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/

Comment: 100% Working solution. See camera switch solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53371645/9222769 https://stackoverflow.com/a/53371634/9222769

Answer (score 5):

```
<script src="/js/webcamjs/webcam.js"></script>

<div id="my_camera" style="width:320px; height:240px;"></div>
<div id="my_result"></div>

<script language="JavaScript">
    Webcam.set('constraints',{
        facingMode: "environment"
    });
    Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );

    function take_snapshot() {
        Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
            document.getElementById('my_result').innerHTML = '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
        } );
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(take_snapshot())">Take Snapshot</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 var constraints = {
    video: true,
    facingMode: "environment"
};
```

Comment: On Chrome I had to give the facingMode value as part of the video value...
   video: { facingMode: "environment" }

Answer (score 2):

In my case to make it work, I had to declare the camera set like this:

```js
Webcam.set({
 width: 250,
 height: 200,
 image_format: 'jpeg',
 jpeg_quality: 90,
 // I add this object constraints
 constraints: {
   facingMode: 'environment'
 }
});
```